# PHP DomParser getting option name and value from xml tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm trying to parse an xml file with PHP. 
I'm using this code and it works well for getting the tagname and the value:

> function getChildNodes($dom,$SearchKey){
>
> ```
>   foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName($SearchKey) as $telefon) {
>       foreach($telefon->childNodes as $node) {
>           print_r(
>           $SearchKey . " : " . $node->nodeValue . "\n"                
>       );
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>   }

example xml of working piece of code:

```
<inputs>
 <input>C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\airbag.mp3</input>
 <input>C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\sunpark.mp3</input>
 <input>C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\rapidarc.mp3</input>
</inputs>
```

example xml of not working piece of code:

```
<instances>
 <instance name="default" state="playing" position="0.050015" time="9290569" length="186489519" rate="1.000000" title="0" chapter="0" can-seek="1" playlistindex="3"/>
</instances>
```

Can someone help me figure out wich options I need to use for getting out the optioname and optionvalue?

all responses are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample for printing out the XML attributes:

```
<?php

$source = '<instances><instance name="default" state="playing" position="0.050015" time="9290569" length="186489519" rate="1.000000" title="0" chapter="0" can-seek="1" playlistindex="3"/></instances>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($source);

$el = $doc->firstChild->firstChild;

for ($i = 0; $i < $el->attributes->length; $i++) {
    $attr = $el->attributes->item($i);
    echo 'Name: '.$attr->name, "\n";
    echo 'Value: '.$attr->value, "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx! I was looking for the $attr->name and $attr->value